# Trying to access array within a hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to parse a hash in ruby. I have an array an array of 'entries'. I want to take each entity and get array of runs within it (I want to store the runs  in a different variable as seen below). My problem is that runs always turns out nil. Below is my code:

```
entries = test_plan['entries']

    entries.each do |ent|
      puts "in entries"
      puts ent
      runs = ent['runs]']
      runs.each do |run|
```

and what an 'entries' hash looks like.

```
{"id"=>"7", "suite_id"=>729, "name"=>"Regression", "runs"=>[{"id"=>2588, "suite_id"=>729}]}
```

Comment: The hash is what "ent" looks like.

Comment: mistake:       runs = ent['runs]'] should be this       runs = ent['runs'].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple typo. Change

```
runs = ent['runs]']
```

to

```
runs = ent['runs']
```